# LLDB is not launching a Clang++ compiled program

Tags: c++, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lldb

I am tying to launch a debugging of clang code via lldb. I'm using a WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I installed a clang and lldb via `sudo apt-get install clang` and `sudo apt-get install lldb` accordingly.

The test code (mytest.cpp) is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation command: `clang++ -g -std=c++17 -o mytest mytest.cpp`

Then I calling a debugger:

```
lldb mytest
(lldb) target create "mytest"
Current executable set to '/home/adzol/Projects/mytest' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 51 launched: '/home/adzol/Projects/mytest' (x86_64)
```

And that's it. Nothing is happening. What can be wrong here?

But if I am calling my executable file directly, I am getting expected console output:

```
./mytest
TEST
```

Comment: You should never call your program `test` because `test` is a shell builtin, so it leads to a lot of confusion.  Call it `mytest` or anything unique.  Also, tell us what happens when you run the program directly, without the debugger.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I edited the question according to your comment.

Comment: Not reproducible here...

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., What do you mean? You tried and all worked properly?

Comment: Yes everything is working.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., I tried to do the same thing via virtual machine and all works properly. Strange thing. So this is a WSL bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was is WSL 1. I updated my WSL to WSL 2 and this all works.